# Facebook signup uses wrong segue within if statement - Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook, swift, segue

So on my first screen of my iOS app I have a “Login” “SignUp” and a “SignUp With Facebook” buttons. The first two buttons link to their own view controllers just fine, and once logged in the simulator will automatically log them in with the:

```
if PFUser.currentUser() != nil {

      self.performSegueWithIdentifier("autoSegue", sender: self)

            } else {
```

Code that you can see at the bottom of the full block of code below. However the Facebook signup I want to transition to a separate view controller where I can show them their profile pic, capture the data on Parse, have them enter a user name, then segue to the same view controller that the SignUp and Login go to – autoSegue. I have all the code on that view controller already written out, but my problem is that when they click the signup button for Facebook, it takes them through the autoSegue and not the fbSignup segue (the one that links to where I want to capture the FB data). Both segues are linked directly from the view controller (not the buttons themselves), and I receive no build errors. I appreciate any help.

Thanks!

Full code:

```
import UIKit

import Parse

import MediaPlayer

import FBSDKCoreKit







class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var loginAlpha: UIButton!

    @IBOutlet var signupAlpha: UIButton!




    var avPlayer: AVPlayer!

    var avPlayerLayer: AVPlayerLayer!

    var paused: Bool = false





    @IBAction func facebookSignup(sender: AnyObject) {



        let permissions = ["public_profile"]



        PFFacebookUtils.logInInBackgroundWithReadPermissions(permissions) { (user: PFUser?, error: NSError?) -> Void in



            if let error = error {



                print(error)



            } else {



                if let user = user {



                    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("fbSignup", sender: self)

                }





            }





        }







    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()




        // code for background video



                let theURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("test", withExtension: "mp4")



                avPlayer = AVPlayer(URL: theURL!)

                avPlayerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: avPlayer)

                avPlayerLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill

                avPlayer.volume = 0

                avPlayer.actionAtItemEnd = AVPlayerActionAtItemEnd.None



                avPlayerLayer.frame = view.layer.bounds

                view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor();

                view.layer.insertSublayer(avPlayerLayer, atIndex: 0)



                NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self,

                    selector: "playerItemDidReachEnd:",

                    name: AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification,

                    object: avPlayer.currentItem)

            }



            func playerItemDidReachEnd(notification: NSNotification) {

                let p: AVPlayerItem = notification.object as! AVPlayerItem

                p.seekToTime(kCMTimeZero)

            }



            override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {



                if PFUser.currentUser() != nil {



                    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("autoSegue", sender: self)

                } else {







                signupAlpha.alpha = 0

                loginAlpha.alpha = 0



                UIView.animateWithDuration(1.5, delay: 1.0, options: [], animations: { () -> Void in

                    self.signupAlpha.alpha = 1.0

                    self.loginAlpha.alpha = 1.0



                    }, completion: nil)



                    avPlayer.play()

                    paused = false

            }

    }



            override func viewDidDisappear(animated: Bool) {

                avPlayer.pause()

                paused = true

            }







    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {

        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using Storyboards? You may have messed up on the storyboard and connected the segue to the wrong ViewController.

I can't see anything particularly wrong with your code.

Comment: I am. I used the main storyboard to design everything and ctrl dragged from the main view controller (the yellow dot on the top) to the other view controllers I wanted to segue to (autoSegue and fbSignup) and picked “Show”. Can I have 2 segues going like that from the same source? Is that where I messed up? Should I have put the fbSignup segue on the button instead of the view controller?